# CD eject notification in Windows

Tags: windows

My program needs to know when a user ejects cd disc. Is there some sort of notification for this in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For non-.NET languages, you add a message handler for the WM_DEVICECHANGE message and check for a WPARAM of DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE. The LPARAM points to a DEV_BROADCAST_HDR structure; it's dbch_devicetype member gives the devicetype.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some VB code that shows you how its done.

```
Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim we As New WMIEvent
        Dim w As ManagementEventWatcher = Nothing
        Dim q As WqlEventQuery
        Dim observer As New ManagementOperationObserver

        ' Bind to local machine
        Dim opt As New ConnectionOptions
        opt.EnablePrivileges = True 'sets required privilege
        Dim scope As New ManagementScope("root\CIMV2", opt)

        Try
            q = New WqlEventQuery
            q.EventClassName = "__InstanceModificationEvent"
            q.WithinInterval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)

            ' DriveType - 5: CDROM
            q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk'" & _
                " and TargetInstance.DriveType = 5"
            w = New ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q)

            ' register async. event handler
            AddHandler w.EventArrived, AddressOf we.CDREventArrived
            w.Start()

            ' Do something usefull,block thread for testing
            Console.ReadLine()
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        Finally
            w.Stop()
        End Try

    End Sub 'Main


    ' Dump all properties
    Public Sub CDREventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)
        ' Get the Event object and display it
        Dim pd As PropertyData = e.NewEvent.Properties("TargetInstance")

        If Not (pd Is Nothing) Then
            Dim mbo As ManagementBaseObject = pd.Value '

            ' if CD removed VolumeName == null
            If Not (mbo.Properties("VolumeName").Value Is Nothing) Then
                Console.WriteLine("CD has been inserted")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("CD has been ejected")
            End If
        End If

    End Sub 'CDREventArrived
```